# Change the token price during ICO

Tags: contract-development

Just that, is there any way to change the token price during the ICO execution? automatic or manual? some documentation or example? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A token contract is software, so, yes there is a way to change the token price in the middle of an ICO--but--and this is a very big "but"--only if that piece of software had been written to allow for that.

Ethereum smart contracts are immutable. Once deployed, they cannot be changed. So unless the token contract was programmed to have a changeable price, you wouldn't be able to change it.

***Side note:*** I would never in a million years buy tokens from a smart contract that had the ability for someone to change the price during the sale. I would advise anyone who asked me not to participate either. What would stop you from selling me and the first 100 people tokens for 100 ethers per token and then change it so you and your friends get tokens for 1 ether a piece? That sounds like a very bad idea to me, and I would never invest in it, which is why it's so important for everyone to read the source before they invest.

Comment: hmm, i really appreciate your answer; and I really didn't think about the scenario you presented to me because i don't really thought in that way, thank you for your help man

Comment: Solidity programming is very interesting. As a programmer, you have to assume all your users are evil. As a user, you always have to assume the programmers are evil. Otherwise, you're opening yourself up to be stolen from.

Comment: Thank you for your reply man, i'll save that words ;). Getting back to the post topic, if i want to do an ICO with phases, i mean 25% discount in the first phase, 10% for the second, something like that; will that apply the same response you gave me?

Comment: Stack exchange is probably going to make us go into a private chat soon, but I'll answer it this way: if the source code was public, and the source code programmed the sale that way, and I could see the source and convince myself that it made sense, then "yes, definitely." The whole idea is that no-one has to trust anyone any more because we have a system that allows us not to trust (other than by reading the source and convincing ourselves that the code works as ***we*** (the end user) want it to work.